# Can I use checkPermission instead of checkSelfPermission on android +24?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

According to [this document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)),

> to check if you have a permission, call the
>   ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()

And [this document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkPermission(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) says:

> [Context].checkPermission() is to determine whether the given
>   permission is allowed for a particular process and user ID running in
>   the system

I've the following code on android 24:

```
smsPerm = "android.permission.SEND_SMS";
int result = checkPermission(smsPerm, Process.myPid(), Process.myUid());
```

the `result` would be:

- `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` if `smsPerm` is added to manifest and is granted on runtime.
- `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` if `smsPerm` is added to manifest but is not granted on runtime.
- `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` if `smsPerm` is not added to manifest.

With that saying, it seems the behavior is the same as `checkSelfPermission` on android +24. Can I use `checkPermission` instead of `checkSelfPermission`?

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question and deserve more attention. just started a bounty to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am uncertain what you think you are gaining... but, yes, you can use `Context#checkPermission()` instead of `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`.

The implementation of `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` uses `Context#checkPermission()`, at least [at the time that I posted this answer](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat.java#L520-L536).

```
public static int checkSelfPermission(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String permission) {
    if (permission == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("permission is null");
    }

    return context.checkPermission(permission, android.os.Process.myPid(), Process.myUid());
}
```

For the long term, it would be safer to use `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`. That can be updated to reflect new rules applied in new versions of Android.

Comment: The gain is not to use the `support` library because of the requirements in the project I'm working on!

Comment: @AmirRezazadeh: Those requirements are not sustainable for the long term.